# Android View Pager - Carousel

Tags: android-viewpager, carousel

Im getting this error, when using this in my project https://github.com/mrleolink/SimpleInfiniteCarousel

300-303/system_process D/dalvikvm: GC_CONCURRENT freed 962K, 35% free 6764K/10268K, paused 6ms+9ms, total 85ms
07-18 12:33:01.595      648-794/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: Received deviceId from Email app: null
07-18 12:33:01.595      648-794/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! deviceId unknown; stopping self and retrying
07-18 12:33:06.616      648-648/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = false, running = false
07-18 12:33:06.626      300-462/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-18 12:33:06.626      648-662/com.android.exchange D/ExchangeService: !!! Email application not found; stopping self
07-18 12:33:06.636      300-496/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { act=com.android.email.ACCOUNT_INTENT } U=0: not found
07-18 12:33:06.656      648-648/com.android.exchange E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d36620 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d36620 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 12:33:06.666      648-648/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40d36620 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.test(ServiceProxy.java:191)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1850)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 12:33:06.676      300-311/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@412fde60
07-18 12:33:06.687      648-648/com.android.exchange E/ActivityThread: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf0780 that was originally bound here
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf0780 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 12:33:06.687      648-648/com.android.exchange E/StrictMode: null
        android.app.ServiceConnectionLeaked: Service com.android.exchange.ExchangeService has leaked ServiceConnection com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy$ProxyConnection@40cf0780 that was originally bound here
        at android.app.LoadedApk$ServiceDispatcher.(LoadedApk.java:969)
        at android.app.LoadedApk.getServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:863)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1418)
        at android.app.ContextImpl.bindService(ContextImpl.java:1407)
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.bindService(ContextWrapper.java:473)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:157)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.ServiceProxy.setTask(ServiceProxy.java:145)
        at com.android.emailcommon.service.AccountServiceProxy.getDeviceId(AccountServiceProxy.java:116)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService.getDeviceId(ExchangeService.java:1249)
        at com.android.exchange.ExchangeService$7.run(ExchangeService.java:1856)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:551)
        at com.android.emailcommon.utility.Utility$2.doInBackground(Utility.java:549)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
07-18 12:33:06.706      300-497/system_process W/ActivityManager: Unbind failed: could not find connection for android.os.BinderProxy@4114f950

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the issue is not related with carousel. This exception is from the device system